# Implementing unit conversions

Tags: java, logic

I am working on a function where I am calculating meter units to amount. Rules for meter calcualtions are :

- Minimum fare on 1.6km   amt - 12/-
- Subsequent 1 km         amt - 7/-
- 25% additional fare for journey for midnight

The function I have written is :

```
public static void CalculateAutoFare(int kmIndex) {
    double fare = 12.00;
    double night = 15.00;
    double subseIncre = 1.50;
    double nightIncre = 0.25;
    int j=0;

    for (int i=1; i <= kmIndex; i++) {

        if (i == 3 || j == 4) {
            fare += 1.00f;
            j =0;
        } 
        else {
            fare += subseIncre;
            j++;
        }
        fare = Math.round(fare*2f)/2f;
        double extra = ((double) fare * nightIncre);
        night = fare + extra;
        night = Math.round(night*2f)/2f;

        System.out.println("I = " + i + " Fare = " + fare + " Night = " + night + " 25%Extra = " + extra);
    }

    System.out.println("Day = " + fare + " Night = " + night);
}
```

kmIndex is the index of km. Meter readings are as 1.00, 1.10, 1.20, 1.30...1.90, 2.00.... Thus kmIndex for 1.00 = 0, 1.10 = 1, 1.20 - 3 and so on.

Results that I get as per code and should be is mentioned below :

[image]

I have worked till 4.00 and where the results are not right are declared undet Should Be of relevant to Day or Night.

I worked a lot on this but couldn't get results as expected. If I try to correct 1 thing then other gets wrong or doesn't give expected results. Can anyone help me out with this. Have spent almost whole day trying to solve this.

Comment: Could you explain the column "Should be". In the firt case, why should be 19 instead of 18.5? Could you show the steps to achieve this result?

Comment: Results of "Should Be" are as per here : http://www.trafficpolicemumbai.org/new_auto_tariff_card.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've analyzed the worksheet and I haven't found a formula that gives the results shown there. It seems that some values have some rounding differences. I've realized that only the values with 25 or 75 cents were different. For example, you calculated 18,5 and it should be 19 (the result was 18,75 and you rounded down to 18,5, but it should be rounded up to 19).
So, if you don't have the original formula that was used to create the table, I think the only way to be sure that the results will match the worksheet is to hardcode it. It's not an elegant solution, but it guarantees the correct result.

Answer (score 0):

Small tweak in the code did the trick. You wanted .75 round as .5 so instead of multiply by 2 multiply by it's immediate smaller float.

```
{
            double fare = 12.00;
            double night = 15.00;
            double subseIncre = 1.50;
            double nightIncre = 0.25;
            int j=0;

            for (int i=1; i <= 22; i++) {

                if (i == 3 || j == 4) {
                    fare += 1.00f;
                    j =0;
                }
                else {
                    fare += subseIncre;
                    j++;
                }

                double extra = ((double) fare * nightIncre);
                night = fare + extra;
                ;

                System.out.println("I = " + i + " Fare = " + fare + " Night = " + night + " 25%Extra = " + extra);
            }
            System.out.println("actual Day = " + fare + " Night = " + night);

            fare = Math.round(fare*1.99f)/2f;
            night = Math.round(night*1.99f)/2f;
            System.out.println("rounded Day = " + fare + " Night = " + night);
    }
```

Comment: with the above code I get many figures wrong which were coming right. Their is no need to change the fare = Math.round as that is coming proper. I added an if(i >= 11 && i <= 22) i.e. all of 2.0 to 3.0, then use night*2f/2f else use 1.99f. With that change I get only 3 figures wrong in 3.x. I got to use this also for xx.xx. Wondering how many if's will I have to add ??

Comment: yeah, i missed to validate with other inputs... you probably need an if in this case...